# CORS blocks a request from frontend to Flask server when started with docker compose

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose, cors

**Description**
I have a React application that makes the following request:

```
await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_MASTER_HOST}/api/agl-history`, { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }, data: { label, date } });
```

In some cases it works but when the backend is started with `docker-compose up -d`, it gives me the following in Chrome:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/agl-history' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

**When it works**

- When I manually build the image with `sudo docker build . -t test` and run, `sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 -t test`, it works perfectly
- When I run the flask server with `flask run --host=0.0.0.0`

**When it does not work**

- `docker-compose up -d`

// docker-compose.yml, relevant service is `master`

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  agl-history:
    depends_on:
        - mariadb
    build: ./agl-history
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
        - main
  master:
    depends_on:
        - mariadb
    build: ./master
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
        - 8080:8080
    networks:
        - main
  mariadb:
    image: "mariadb:10.5.10"
    restart: on-failure
    environment: 
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MARIADB_PASSW}
    ports:
        - 3306:3306
    volumes:
        - /var/lib/docker/volumes/add3-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
        - main
networks:       
    main:
        driver: bridge
```

// Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9.5-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

ENV FLASK_RUN_PORT 8080
ENV FLASK_APP source/server_config.py

CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

// Flask endpoint

```
from datetime import date
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify
from datetime import datetime
from flask_cors import CORS

# app reference
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)

# This method executes before any API request
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    print('before API request')

@app.route('/api/agl-history', methods=['GET'])
def get_agl_history():
    print('during')
    response = jsonify([
        {
            'id': 1,
            'customerId': 777,
            'campaignName': 'Test campaing',
            'adGroupName': 'Test ad group',
            'execDate': datetime.now(),
            'label': '92'
        }
    ]
    )
    return response

# This method executes after every API request.
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    return response
```

**Notes**

- React frontend and server backend is going to be run on different hosts eventually

What am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue comes from your Flask backend and it's CORS headers. I'd suggest using --host=127.0.0.1 in your flask command. Also, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43881141/16198415) answer, it provides a lot of information.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that browser is sending preflight ( OPTIONS ) request because you have Authorization headers , i had same problem before with react dev server and express,

I solved the problem with , OPTIONS route on same path with :

Access-Control-Request-Headers : Authorization

But i am maybe wrong here , because cors is confusing thing :)

Answer (score 0):

[Browers issue preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) request(OPTION call) when the origin (frontend localhost:3000) is different from the API origin (localhost:8080)

For development, you can allow all the origin in the flask server. This is the [default configuration](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#default-values). Seems this is the case with your working scenarios

But when running via the docker-compose the hostname of the flask server would be `master`. From your failing scenario, it seems, flask does only accept from that hostname.

So when deploying in a production environment I would suggest adding cors origin configuration allowed origin as front end domain

For your docker-compose scenario, you could configure below in flask server

```
CORS_ORIGINS: “localhost:3000”
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not realize that docker-compose does not rebuild images by default so I was using an older build that did not have CORS enabled.

The only change that was needed to fix the issue was:

```
cors = CORS(app, origins="*")
```

when starting flask server. Then, start the services with:

```
sudo docker-compose up -d --build master
```